# PHP and mysqli: Select with multiple conditions using prepared statements

Tags: php, select, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm working on some prepared statements using *mysqli* in a php file with a database running on *InnoDB*.  Most of the statements are working pretty well, but I have a select statement with multiple conditions that keeps returning a syntax error in my select statement, to be specific:   near `? AND section_num = ? AND dept = ? AND semester = ? AND year = ?` at line 1 as well as the following error:

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object.
```

Here's the snippet of code:

```
if (!$rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM courses WHERE course_num = ? AND section_num = ? AND dept = ? AND semester = ? AND year = ?")) {
        echo "Select Query Failed!: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") ". $mysqli->error;
    }
    if(!$rs->bind_param("ssssi", mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$course_num), mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$section_num),
        mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$dept), mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$semester), mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$year))) {
        echo "Select Binding parameters failed: (" . $rs->errno .") " . $rs->error;
    }
    if (!$rs->execute()) {
        echo "Execute select failed: (" . $rs->errno . ") " . $rs->error;
    }
```

Any suggestions for how to form this statement to retrieve an id based on the 4 inputs would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `prepare` to prepare a statement, not `query` as that just executes a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "
SELECT id 
FROM courses 
WHERE 
course_num = ? AND section_num = ? AND dept = ? AND semester = ? AND year = ?
";
$rs = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$rs->bind_param("ssssi", $course_num, $section_num, $dept, $semester, $year);
$rs->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change: `$mysqli->query("SELECT id ...`
To: `$mysqli->prepare("SELECT id ...`

Answer (score -2):

It is quite simple just do this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$table_tran` WHERE `$mem_id` ='$member_id' and                         $status` = '$cur_status'";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

It gets the data from the transaction table using the `and` statement.